# Simple Asymptotic Question

Tags: asymptotics

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out the asymptotic
of $(1 + x)^{1/k}$, where $x$ is going to $0$ and $k$ is a fixed positive integer.
I know it is going to 1, but I wanted to know the second term and
the O-bound if possible.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The [Taylor polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) will give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you!! Greatly appreciated!!